# Android application and Bluetooth commercial subscription

Tags: android, bluetooth, payment

I'm developing an Android BLE App for pairing smartphones with a specific type of custom made devices. With this application you can control it remotely sending and receiving data. Those devices are an industrial product,and they'll be sell soon on the market. The app will be released for free on the Google Play Store.

The question is : should I pay for use Bluetooth technology and the bt logo?
The bill is not cheap..8k$ and taking a look at the Play Store i saw a lot of non-free app with the bt logo,all of them payed the 8k subscription tax required by the bt foundation?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is asking about licensing fees, a legal aspect, not programming

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pay for the Android app, but for the peripheral device itself if you use any of the Bluetooth trademarks (logo for instance).

Comment: Thank you for the reply,[here](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/qualification-listing/qualification-listing-fees) you can check the listing fees provided by the Bluetooth foundation. Looking at that document in the worst case scenario i have to pay 100$ for the app and 8k$ for the device. I do not use any Bluetooth trademarks,btw i am a little bit afraid of what i have to do..